# Vertical element alignment in table cells

Tags: html

Problem is following: on 18th day, the monthday box is at the top, but other day boxes are centered because there are no other element in that cell. So  I want to glue the month days to the top.

How can I accomplish this?

```
td.calendar-day-np {
  width:150px;
  padding:5px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #999;
  border:1px solid #999;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nurgasemetey/WLSfs)

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: try `vertical-align:top;` in css! (`style="vertical-align:top;"`)

Comment: @Philip You should provide the answer via the answer function rather than simply a comment.

Comment: @Philip, it would be fair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `vertical-align:top;` in css! (`style="vertical-align:top;"`)